# Crop UIWebView with Swift on Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, xcode6

I want to crop part of my UIWebView so I can take away part of the website. I want to take off some room from the top of a website. Here is my code so you can tell me what I have to do to crop it. I've just started to code so explaining a little what your doing will help heaps!:

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class WebView: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

var URLPath = "http://www.google.com.au"




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    loadAdressURL()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func loadAdressURL(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:requestURL!)
    Webview.loadRequest(request)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property. We can adjust the insets of the the `scrollView` like so:

```
let topSpace = -100    //or however large 
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topSpace, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

The final line is so the user can't scroll up and see the cut off piece.

Comment: I put that in exactly how you wrote it out but I'm getting an error on the second line. its saying that there is a "Expected Declaration" and there is a small red arrow under the first w of web view.

Comment: I recommend you use lower case variable names. Change `@IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!` to `@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error "Expected Declaration" on the second line. I changed the IBOutlet to all lower case but it's still not working. Are you able to copy all my code into your Xcode and check your code to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BenJamminnn/223bd7e5701a5e9fc049 , I've tested this on my machine.